# After transforming UIView to UIScrollView using my method the new UIScrollView only appears for a split second. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to write a method that takes in a UIView as a parameter and outputs a UIScrollView. When I run the code the view turns into a UIScrollView for a split second and then disappears. I have a feeling that the problem has to do with the line:  self = [super init]; Here is the code:

```
//.h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ControlSectorScrollView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {

}

- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view;

@end

//.m file

@implementation ControlSectorScrollView

- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view {

    self = [UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame];

    if (self) {
        CGRect contentViewRect = view.frame;
        self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentViewRect.size.width * 2, contentViewRect.size.height);
        self.pagingEnabled = YES;
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        [self addSubview:view];

        CGRect followingSectionFrame = contentViewRect;
        followingSectionFrame.origin.x += contentViewRect.size.width;
        UIView *followingSectionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:followingSectionFrame];
        [self addSubview:followingSectionView];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

EDIT: Please read my comment for more context.

Comment: I'm not completely clear what you're after here- reading between the lines I'm guessing you have a `UIView` that's too large to fit onto the screen, and you want a convenience method for inserting it in a `UIScrollView` - is that correct? btw - all the subviews in your constructor will disappear at the end of the method because they are in local variables and none have been added as subviews to the main view i.e. `self`. Also, putting scrollviews inside scrollviews is almost always a very bad idea, in my experience

Comment: @RichTolley Hello, thanks for the response. I apologize for being unclear. I edited the code, hopefully making it more clear. I am making a method that turns a UIView into a UIScrollView. Can you please clarify about the subviews disappearing/how to remedy the issue? Also I am not putting a scrollview in a scrollview I am going to run this method on a UIView, remove the UIView and replace it with the newly generated UIScrollView, but keeping the content that is in the UIView.